# 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'cell'

Tags: excel, object, copy, cell, attributeerror

---

---

```
import os, shutil
from tkinter import *            #tkinter stands for toolkit interface
from tkinter import filedialog
import re 
import xlwings as xw 

file_names = xw.Book(filedialog.askopenfilename())
file_names_sh = file_names.sheets['fe_0.85']

folder_source_train = filedialog.askdirectory()
train_destination   = r'D:\Machine_learning\train/' 

import numpy as np

numbers= re.compile(r'(\d+)')

def numerical_sort(value):
    parts= numbers.split(value)
    parts[1::2]= map(int, part[1::2])
    return parts

def copy_range(start_col, start_row, end_col, end_row, sheet):
    range_selected = []
    for i in range(start_row, end_row + 1, 1):
        row_selected = []
        for j in range(start_col, end_col + 1, 1):
            row_selected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)
        range_selected.append(row_selected)

    return range_selected

selectedRange_train = copy_range(1, 1, 2, 100, file_names_sh)
```

I encountered error like 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'cell'. There seems to be a problem with "copy_range(~~)" in the code mentioned above. What should I add?  I have no idea what or how to fix it. Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An error of type:

`[1]: object has no attribute attr`
usually refers to the class not having any specific method implemented with that name, for your case object sheet doesn't have a method cell implemented on it, either the attribute you are looking to use is `cells` as per the source code: [cells](https://github.com/xlwings/xlwings/blob/d7e025058cf5e684adb066a9848cc45b4e63ad01/xlwings/main.py#L1441) or the specific attribute exists in an older version of xlwings

Comment: Thank Y for yr comments!